# Is there any python machine learning library that can return coefficients or geometric margin for linear svm?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

Is there any python machine learning library that can return coefficients or geometric margin for linear svm? I know how to let mlpy library return a predictor, but have no idea if it can return the actual coefficients. Thank you!

Comment: [Sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) has this class, which seems to have a `.coeff_` attribute

Answer (score 5):

scikit-learn's [`LinearSVC`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) and [`SGDClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) both implement linear SVMs and both export `coef_` and `intercept_` attributes for model inspection.

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the scikit-learn developers.)